# Filter noise in a dataset containing walking trajectory

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I've a dataset containing the position of a person walking in a indoor environment at a given time.
I don't have any information about the environment, just the dataset.
The table is structured like this:

`(ID, X, Y, time)`

where ID is the primary key containing the id, X and Y the coordinates and time is the timestamp.
The frequency for the data gathering is of 1 element every 0.2 seconds.

Before I start any analysis on the path, speeds etc I'd like to remove the noise from the dataset but I'm not sure what approach I should use.
I've read about using clustering functions like DBSCAN and for given parameters it seems to do something but since it's a clustering based on density I don't feel like it's the best solution. On the other hand ST-DBSCAN takes into account the time so it seems more appropriate but it's still based on density.

Is there a better way to filter noise in a context like this or is DBSCAN the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

If you think of your data as 2-dimensional time-series, then it makes sense to apply one of the algorithms listed here: https://github.com/rob-med/awesome-TS-anomaly-detection